# CDK - Secure Method to Include Necessary Secrets in API Gateway Event Target

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I have the following API Gateway EventBus event target defined in CDK:

```
const key =
      cdk.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(
        this,
        'key',
        process.env.key,
      );
    new cdk.aws_events.Rule(this, 'KeyRule', {
      eventBus: eventBus,
      eventPattern: {
        detailType: ['my.event'],
      },
      targets: [
        new cdk.aws_events_targets.ApiGateway(apiGateway, {
          path: `/key`,
          method: 'POST',
          headerParameters: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'api-key': `${key
              .secretValueFromJson('password')
              .toString()}`,
          },
        }),
      ],
    });
```

This generates properly and works. It keeps the secret ARN in the CloudFormation template *before deployment* and correctly resolves after deployment. The problem is the key is completely in plain sight in the console. Furthermore, if I generate the CloudFormation template for the Event Target Rule *after deployment* it has the fully resolved, plaintext password sitting in the template.

This seems like a major security flaw, so I am trying to do this another way. Theres no way around my need to include this key as part of the request against the API I am targeting with this event.

What would be the best/most secure way to do this? Thanks. Ignore the terrible names, they are placeholders just for this question.

Comment: I'd be shocked if the CDK were leaking your secret's value locally.  Please edit the question with details about the observed leak.  The `fromSecretCompleteArn` method doesn't "look up" your secret from AWS.  The CDK itself does not perform `GetSecret` calls.  Your code will synthesize the secret as a CloudFormation [dynamic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/cfn-example_reference-secret.html) that is resolved cloud-side at deploy-time.  Something like `"{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:<SECRET-ARN>:SecretString:password::}}"`  Perfectly safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate the CloudFormation template for the Event Target Rule after deployment"? You mean the generated template in your `cdk.out` folder changes? That doesn't sound right. The concern about the API key being in plaintext in the console is valid, though - a secure solution would be using a Lambda target that would fetch the key from SecretsManager, or using IAM authorization in your API - you'll have to test to see whether EventBridge signs its requests with AWS credentials, though.

Comment: @fedonev The question is accurate to exactly where the leak occurs. The CloudFormation template generated for deployment has that dynamic reference in it, as I mentioned in the original prompt. The issue is that once deployment has completed, if navigate to the target rule within the AWS console, that secret key is displayed in plain text in the "Target" tab under "Additional parameters".

Comment: @gshpychka Not the `cdk.out`. Seems like the `cdk.out` has that secrets manager reference in it. I can see the key in two places: 1) when I navigate to the target rule, under the "Target" tab as an "Additional parameter" and 2) on that target rule, if I generate the CloudFormation template (button at the top of the console, just below the rule name), it is displayed there as well. As I mentioned, the CloudFormation template upon deployment is safe with the reference. Only after in the console is it unsafe.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Rules don't support native secret references, so you'll have to go for one of the solutions I've mentioned.

Comment: @gshpychka Yeah, it does make sense it would permanently resolve after, and the lambda target suggestion is interesting. I was hoping for something simpler, but that is likely what I will go with. For the time being, the actual external security risk this causes is non-existent, so not super worried about resolving immediately. Thanks for the suggestion.